# How to add Event listener to image defined inside javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add event listener to image which is defined inside java script so that if the user clicks on image it will be redirected to other HTML page? I am using canvas element.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
    <head>
    <style>
     body {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     }
     </style>
     </head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="1000"></canvas>
<script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.strokeRect(188,50,237,473); //This is for generating outer rectangle
      context.fillStyle="FFFFFF";
      context.fillRect(188,50,237,473);
      context.strokeRect(200,90,213,365); //This is for generating the inner rectangle
      context.fillStyle="grey";
      context.fillRect(200,90,213,365);
      context.strokeRect(284,50,40,5); //This is for generating small notch at top
      context.fillStyle="grey";
      context.fillRect(284,50,40,5);
      var leftArrow = new Image();
      leftArrow.addEventListener('load', eventleftArrowLoaded , false);
      leftArrow.src = "leftArrow.jpg";
      function eventleftArrowLoaded() {
        drawScreen();
      }
     function drawScreen() {
     context.drawImage(leftArrow, 218, 482);//leftArrow
}
</script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is just an off-screen bitmap whose pixel contents you happen to have copied into the canvas.  It cannot receive events because it's not present in the DOM.

You need to add the `click` event listener to the canvas, not the image:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', myfunc, false);
```

If you wish to ensure that only clicks within the region covered by the image are directed to the new page you'll need to examine the mouse click coordinates.

Comment: I didn't get you, can you explain in detail

Comment: the `Image` has no on-screen "presence", so it can't receive events.

Comment: I have one more code which might make the Image a clickable one, But i am unable to embed it in my original code, here is the code

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <title>LeftArrow</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: ivory;">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300 style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
  <script>
  var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var offsetX=BB.left;
  var offsetY=BB.top;
  var startX,startY;
  var isDown=false;
  var PI2=Math.PI*2;

Comment: canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;
  var imgX=50;
  var imgY=50;
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=start;
  img.src="leftArrow.jpg";
   function start(){
     ctx.drawImage(img,50,50);
   }

  function handleMousedown(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     var x=e.clientX-offsetX;
     var y=e.clientY-offsetY;

     if(x>=imgX && x<=imgX+img.width && y>=imgY && y<=imgY+img.height){
       alert('Clicked in left arrow');
     }
  }
</script> 
</body>
</html>